# Is there a faster way of writing OR operator?

Tags: javascript

Is there a faster way of writing this?

```
if ($('#id').val()==7 || $('#id').val()==8 || $('#id').val()==9){
    console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

I'm thinking of something like:

```
if ($('#id').val()== 7||8||9){
    console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

Comment: I made a little jsperf comparing the current answers http://jsperf.com/or-operator-vs-indexof `indexOf` is marginally faster in my Chrome browser.

Comment: @vache I was asking shorter to write, not faster to run. Having said that, thank you for the jsPerf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```
if ([7,8,9].indexOf(+$('#id').val()) > -1){
    console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

The above function will work in IE9+, for older browser's you can use either [PolyFill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) or [jQuery.inArray(value, array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/))

```
if (jQuery.inArray(+$('#id').val(),[7,8,9]) > -1){
    console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

Comment: There's also a linear search in the original `||`, so it's no worse.

Comment: @user2864740, this code will `[7,8,9].indexOf(+"7")` notice a `+` sign

Comment: this doesn't work for IE8 which might be a dealbreaker for people.

Answer (score 7):

The best thing you can do to speed up your code is to cache that DOM reference:

```
var idval = +$('#id').val();
if (idval === 7 || idval === 8 || idval === 9) { ...  }
```

Of course if it's really those three values, then:

```
if (idval >= 7 && idval <= 9) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a switch:

```
switch($('#id').val()){
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('value of #id is NOT 7, 8, or 9!')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ***[$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)***

```
if($.inArray(+$('#id').val(),[7,8,9])) > -1)
    console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really much simpler, unless the list of values is really long:

```
if ([7, 8, 9].indexOf(parseInt($('#id').val(), 10)) != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this one to the jsperf: the **in** operator.  The value in every key:value (e.g. 7:7) pair is irrelevant here.

```
if ($('#id').val() in {7:7, 8:8, 9:9}) {
  console.log('value of #id is 7, 8, or 9!')
};
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in